# SWIFT - get county info from mapkit

Tags: swift, mapkit

Is there a way to get county information within the mapkit api?   I can't seem to find a way.

Answer (score 2):

In CLPlacemark you can use subAdministrativeArea.

```
var subAdministrativeArea: String? { get }
```

Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/subAdministrativeArea) to the docs.